# Rails 3, handling ajax response

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

Using Ruby on Rails 3, I have a page with a list of comments and I want to show a form using ajax whenever the user presses a comment's *reply* button.

So far, I have a partial called `_form_comment.html.erb` with the html for the form. There's no problem with this.

In the view, this is the code for the *reply* buttons:

```
link_to "Reply", {:controller => "catalog", :action => "form_comment", :id => c.id}, :remote => true, :class => "btn_reply_comment"
```

In the controller, I've added this action, that returns the partial whenever a *reply* button is pressed:

```
def form_comment
    if request.xhr?
        render:partial => "form_comment"
    end
end
```

And, in order to "do something" with the response, I have this script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn_reply_comment")
        .bind("ajax:success", 
              function() { alert("Ajax response"); });
});
```

When I press the *reply* button, I can check, using Firebug, that the ajax request is returning a `304 not modified` code. I've read some other threads saying that I should disable the cache in the ajax request, but given I'm not manually using `$.ajax...`, I don't know how to modify that.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to bind to the "ajax:success" event on the form created by the link_to helper, and not on the "a" link element.

so try to bind to:

```
".btn_reply_comment form"
```

Anyway I suggest using a normal link_to or "a" element, and some jquery code to make the ajax request and handle the callback like:

```
$(".btn_reply_comment").on("click", function(){
   $.get($(this).attr("href"), function(data){
     eval(data)
   })
})
```

ps: "on" requires jquery >= 1.7, if you don't have it use "bind"